# Unity Error CS1503 Convert 'UnityEngine.A.P.A.AndroidPlatform' to 'UnityEngine.A.P.IPurchasingEventSender'

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm trying to build my game but this error came up after implementing the ads and after fixing all other JDK, SDK and NDK related errors.

On the Unity console it says the following:

...droid/**AndroidPlatform.cs(27,44)**: error **CS1503**: Argument 1: cannot convert from '**UnityEngine.Advertisements.Platform.Android.AndroidPlatform**' to '**UnityEngine.Advertisements.Purchasing.IPurchasingEventSender**'.

Tip: The "AndroidPlatform.cs" script came automatically with the packages installed.

The line with the error has asterisks:

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
using System;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements.Purchasing;

namespace UnityEngine.Advertisements.Platform.Android
{
internal class AndroidPlatform : AndroidJavaProxy, INativePlatform, IPurchasingEventSender
{
    private IPlatform m_Platform;
    private AndroidJavaObject m_CurrentActivity;
    private AndroidJavaClass m_UnityAds;
    private IPurchase m_UnityAdsPurchase;
    private AndroidJavaClass m_Placement;
    public AndroidPlatform() : base("com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsListener") {}

    public void Initialize(string gameId, bool testMode, bool enablePerPlacementLoad, IUnityAdsInitializationListener initializationListener)
    {
        m_UnityAdsPurchase = new Purchase();
        **m_UnityAdsPurchase?.Initialize(this);**
        m_UnityAds?.CallStatic("initialize", m_CurrentActivity, gameId, testMode, enablePerPlacementLoad, new AndroidInitializationListener(m_Platform, initializationListener));
    }
```

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Comment: Can you include a [mre] in the question? This should include steps to reproduce the problem starting from an empty project, including which plugins to install, etc. My best guess is that you have stuff from two different versions of the Advertising packages intermingling. You may even be able to fix it by removing the package completely then importing it again.